# Groupby max and min value of each month over the years

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, python-datetime

I'm trying to plot a chart that shows daily Max and Min temperature from the period of 2005-2014. The temperature is denoted in the *Data_Value* column.

I have a hard time trying to figure out how to proceed here. I need to show the x axis in months instead of years or days.

**Dataset**

```
                     ID Element  Data_Value
Date                                       
2005-01-01  USW00004848    TMIN           0
2005-01-01  USC00207320    TMAX         150
2005-01-01  USC00207320    TMIN         -11
2005-01-01  USW00014833    TMIN         -44
2005-01-01  USW00014833    TMAX          33
.....                                     
2015-12-31  USC00200032    TMAX          11
2015-12-31  USC00205050    TMIN         -17
2015-12-31  USC00208202    TMAX           0
2015-12-31  USC00201250    TMIN          -6
2015-12-31  USC00200230    TMIN         -17
```

**My attempt:**

1. Extract the TMAX and TMIN from the dataset respectively

```
dfMax = df2[df2["Element"] == "TMAX"] 
dfMin = df2[df2["Element"] == "TMIN"]
```

2. Find the daily Max and Min

```
dfMinD = dfMin.Data_Value.resample("d").min()
dfMaxD = dfMax.Data_Value.resample("d").max()
```

I'm stuck here. The plot shows years in x-axis instead of months.

I reckon I need to find the max and min temperature by month instead? How can I group them by months to show the daily max and min of each month(Jan - Dec) through out the period of 2005-2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution is change `d` to `MS` for start of months:

```
dfMax = df2[df2["Element"] == "TMAX"] 
dfMin = df2[df2["Element"] == "TMIN"]

dfMinD = dfMin.Data_Value.resample("MS").min()
dfMaxD = dfMax.Data_Value.resample("MS").max()

df = pd.concat([dfMaxD, dfMinD], axis=1, keys=('max','min'))
```

Another solution for months periods with [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) pass to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `min` and `max`:

```
dfMax = df2[df2["Element"] == "TMAX"] 
dfMin = df2[df2["Element"] == "TMIN"]

dfMaxD = dfMax.groupby(dfMax.index.to_period('m'))['Data_Value'].max()
dfMinD = dfMin.groupby(dfMin.index.to_period('m'))['Data_Value'].min()

print (dfMinD)
Date
2005-01   -44
2015-12   -17
Freq: M, Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64

print (dfMaxD)
Date
2005-01    150
2015-12     11
Freq: M, Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64

df = pd.concat([dfMaxD, dfMinD], axis=1, keys=('max','min'))
print (df)
         max  min
Date             
2005-01  150  -44
2015-12   11  -17
```

Or if need one solution for both first create months PeriodIndex, then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and grouping by first level aggregate `min` and `max`:

```
df = (df2.set_index(df2.index.to_period('m'))
         .set_index(['ID','Element'], append=True)['Data_Value']
         .unstack()
         .groupby(level=0)
         .agg({'TMAX':'max', 'TMIN':'min'}))
print (df)
          TMAX  TMIN
Date                
2005-01  150.0 -44.0
2015-12   11.0 -17.0
```

Comment: it works like a charm! Thanks! And thanks for the reference to DatetimeIndex.to_period, learned something new each day!

Answer (score 1):

```
#df.reset_index(inplace=True) #if date is the index
dfMax=df[df['Element'].eq('TMAX')]
dfMin=df[df['Element'].eq('TMIN')]
```

**for each month Regardless of the year using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [Series.dt.month](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html)**

```
dfMonths_max=dfMax.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)['Data_Value'].max()
dfMonths_min=dfMin.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)['Data_Value'].min()
```

---

```
print(dfMonths_max)
Date
1     150
12     11
Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64
```

---

```
print(dfMonths_min)
Date
1    -44
12   -17
Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64
```

**for each year using [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)**

```
dfMonths_by_age_max=dfMax.resample('M',on='Date')['Data_Value'].max()
dfMonths_by_age_min=dfMin.resample('M',on='Date')['Data_Value'].min()
```

---

```
print(dfMonths_by_age_max)

Date
2005-01-31    150.0
2005-02-28      NaN
2005-03-31      NaN
2005-04-30      NaN
2005-05-31      NaN
              ...  
2015-08-31      NaN
2015-09-30      NaN
2015-10-31      NaN
2015-11-30      NaN
2015-12-31     11.0
Freq: M, Name: Data_Value, Length: 132, dtype: float64
```

---

```
print(dfMonths_by_age_min)


Date
2005-01-31   -44.0
2005-02-28     NaN
2005-03-31     NaN
2005-04-30     NaN
2005-05-31     NaN
              ... 
2015-08-31     NaN
2015-09-30     NaN
2015-10-31     NaN
2015-11-30     NaN
2015-12-31   -17.0
Freq: M, Name: Data_Value, Length: 132, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks for the time taken to help with this. Tried and your solution and it works too!